# Unable to update wordpress

Tags: updates

I have created an ECS Instance in Alibaba Cloud using a Marketplace image powered by IGS(Wordpress on Centos 7.4 64Bits). The installation went fine, but when I am updating, I am getting asked for FTP Details which I am not aware.

[image: Update Notification]

[image: FTP Screen]

How can I find the details of FTP or create one? And what is it used for?

Please find below the link to the documentation of custom Image.
https://mp-intl-article.oss-ap-southeast-1.aliyuncs.com/commodity_user_guide/387d73fb-108d-438b-ac7c-c3b366c647cb.pdf?file=387d73fb-108d-438b-ac7c-c3b366c647cb.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a permissions (solved by chmod) issue.

You don't have enough privileges (755 at least) for WordPress to update. This also means you can't write to `wp-uploads` and so on.

Check this out:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18352682/correct-file-permissions-for-wordpress

Comment: @Smelter Great. Your client should be able to do whatever he wants after.

Comment: Solutions works great!! Thanks. Please upvote if you think this helps others

Comment: @Smelter Glad it helped. Can't upvote my own answer tho, haha. That's on...you *wink*

Comment: :) I mean the question. I can't upvote yours due to low reputation

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact your Hosting provider for it. OR you can find it in your Hosting login.

Or the alternate way to manually update Wordpress would be to do it using your cpanel by going to the File manager. And replacing the wp-includes, wp-admin folder and all the files except the wp-content folder with the latest version of Wordpress.

Comment: I have deployed it in a dedicated instance in Cloud. I resolved the issue manually, but my client is not technically enabled to do this. I also have the complete root permissions. let me know if there is any fix for this. Thanks

Comment: @Smelter Check my answer.